# CListCtrl get index of element based on group it belongs

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, grouping, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl implementing the Groups feature like:

[image]

and I want to get the index of an element, but I don't want its index based on elements of the List Control. What I want is two get two indexes: The index of the group where it belongs, and the index of the element inside the group.

As an example from the image, the "Saw" index would be {1,2}

I wrote the following code to get the indexes:

```
void MyDialog::OnItemChangedListCtrl(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NMLISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;

    if ((pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
        && (pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED))
    {
        CListCtrl* pListCtrl = (CListCtrl*) GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST_CONTROL);
        if (pListCtrl)
        {
            int items_before = 0;

            int index_group= 0;
            int index_inside_group = 0;

            LVGROUP lg = { 0 };
            lg.cbSize = sizeof(LVGROUP);
            lg.mask = LVGF_ITEMS;

            for (gr = 0; gr < pListCtrl->GetGroupCount();gr++)
            {
                pListCtrl->GetGroupInfoByIndex(gr, &lg);

                if (pNMListView->iItem >= items_before && pNMListView->iItem < (items_before + (int) lg.cItems))
                {
                    index_inside_group = pNMListView->iItem - items_before;
                    break;
                }

                items_before += lg.cItems;
            }

            DoThings(index_group, index_inside_group);
        }
    }
}
```

I got both indexes correctly. On `index_group` I get the group index; and in `index_inside_group` I get the index of the item inside the group it belongs.

My question is: Is there a better way to get the indexes than the manual iteration? It is working fine because my list currently is small; but if it grows hugely I doubt it is an efficient approach!